# Expressjs res.redirect(...) is changing the content-type from json to form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, express

I am hosting a site on Heroku and making use of their Piggyback SSL.

To enforce SSL on certain routes, I am using this code:

```
app.all('/user/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if(app.settings.env != "development" && 
     req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.header('host') + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

The redirection works fine and all headers are present. However, the content-type changes from application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Does anyone know if this behaviour is intended or is it a bug? Is there anything I need to do to stop the content-type from changing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all the responses from whole `/users/*` route set are managed as JSON 
Just explicitly set `res.contentType('application/json')` before `next()`. Or just make this for each route that apply before the `res.send()` or `res.render()`